# how to save data in mongodb from python

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

My task is to make server-monitoring tool like Server Density . i have list of server and i want CPU information, ram information, Disk usage etc of each server at every 15 second and print its plot.
i have setup project in django with mongo as backend DB .
i have written python script which can give me these parameters on local System.
now i my task i to store this information in Mongo-DB . i have written models corresponding for each kind of parameters. 
this is the model i have created.

```
class CpuUsage(Document):

    server = ReferenceField(ServerInfo, db_field='se', required=False)
    sys_time = DateTimeField(db_field='st', required=False)
    #CPU=
    usr = StringField(db_field='u', required=False)
    nice = StringField(db_field='n', required=False)
    sys = StringField(db_field='sy', required=False)
    iowait = StringField(db_field='io', required=False)
    irq = StringField(db_field='ir', required=False)
    soft = StringField(db_field='so', required=False)
    steal = StringField(db_field='st', required=False)
    guest = StringField(db_field='g', required=False)
    idle = StringField(db_field='id', required=False)
    meta = {
        'indexes': ['server']
    }
```

and my script has following two function 
1) cpu_info extract cpu parameters into dictionary.

> ```
> def cpu_info():
>     cpu_parameters = {}
>     ram_parmeters = {}
>     p_info = '/home/bhavuk/Desktop/p_info'
>     #p_file = open(p_info, 'w')
>     cmd1 = 'mpstat -P ALL >'+ p_info
>     p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,
>                          shell=True,
>                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
>                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>     cpu_cores=open(p_info, 'r').read().split('\n')
>     #for i in range(0, len(cpu_cores)):
>     #    print i, cpu_cores[i]
>     print "current cpu state:\n"
>     for i in range(2,len(cpu_cores)-1):
>         cpu_parameters[i-2] = cpu_cores[i].split('\t')
>         print cpu_parameters[i-2]
>     save_cpu_info(cpu_parameters)
> ```

2) this saves information contained inside dictionary to mongodb.

> ```
> def save_cpu_info(parameters):
>     s = ServerInfo() #need to correct
>     s.save()
>
>     for i in xrange(0, len(parameters)):
>         c = CpuUsage(server=s)
>         x = parameters[i]
>
>     c.sys_time = x[0]
>     c.CPU_core = x[2]
>     c.usr = x[3]
>     c.nice = x[4]
>     c.sys = x[5]
>     c.iowait = x[6]
>     c.irq = x[7]
>     c.soft = x[8]
>     c.steal = x[9]
>     c.guest = x[10]
>     c.idle = x[11]
>     c.save()
> ```

i am confused with serverfield, how should i use it, my purpose is to run this script on each searver and desing a UI which has option to display informatin about each server .

i want to know am i proceeding in the right direction and how to run this script on each server at interval of 15 seconds each  and to plot the graph .

further improvement will be highly appreciated .
also i would l

Comment: "i am confused with serverfield." What's serverfield? It doesn't appear in your class definition. Are you asking how to run this code repeatedly? (Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/cron-running-job-every-15-seconds, Windows: Scheduled Task)

Comment: server field is reference to particular server on which i will be running my script.

Answer (score 0):

1.To run by scheduled the script you can use crontab, [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/) or
    own daemon. It seems crontab would be more suitable. You do have to
    remember for use the crontab choice you will should make console
    srcript as:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python2.7
>    # import required packages
>    # setup paths to django project
>    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project.settings")
>    sys.path.append(('/path/to/django/project'))
>    ... # your code
>
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>
>    ... # your code
> ```

2.If you want keep data into the one place you should use only one common host of
    the MongoDB. It means that you should use the same ip/domain your server with
    MongoDB instead localhost at the settings.py into each Django
    projects.